# Can't load package DbxCommonDriver180.bpl error. C++ builder XE 5

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5

We currently have a ticket open with Embarcarderro support but we are wondering if someone else have encountered this problem, and if so how did they fix it.

We are currently trying to update our IDE from XE to XE5.  When we compile and run the exe on the same machine we build it on everything works fine.  But when we try to run the exe on another machine that does not have an IDE installed, we are getting the following error.

ERROR in Create_dbExpress_Connections: Can't load package DbxCommonDriver180.bpl.

The problem is, I'm pretty sure that 180 files are used with XE4.  We are not or have ever used XE4 on any of our computers. We are included DBXCommonDriver190.bpl and rtl190.bpl with our exe.

We have tried the following with no success

In the link below, we tried to search for a driver.ini file.  We didn't find the file however we did find a dbxdriver.ini file which had no reference to DBXCommonDriver180.bpl
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119396

We tried dumping all of the 190.bpl files from the build environment to a clean environment, and got the same error.

We were also told that we should probably, make the following changes to our project
C++ Linker->Link with Dynamic RTL = false 
C++ Linker->Link with the Delphi Runtime Library = false 
Packages->Runtime packages->Link with runtime packages = false

When we tried to make these changes, our projects would not compile.

We are trying to use C++builder XE5 update 2 and installed hotfix 2.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with coworkers and Embarcardero support, we found the problem.

We need to bundle a ini file called dbxdrivers.ini and place it in the same directory as the executable file.